# Thinking in Java 4th Edition - is it necessary to make a factory for isolating the code from implementation?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am currently reading "Thinking in Java 4th edition". In the Chapter "Interface" and the sub-chapter "Interfaces and factories", it states the following

> An interface is intended to be a gateway to multiple implementations,
>   and a typical way to  produce objects that fit the interface is the
>   Factory Method design pattern. Instead of calling  a constructor
>   directly, you call a creation method on a factory object which
>   produces an  implementation of the interface—this way, in theory, your
>   code is completely isolated from  the implementation of the interface,
>   thus making it possible to transparently swap one  implementation for
>   another. Here’s a demonstration showing the structure of the Factory 
>   Method:

(for easy reference, the example codes quoted after my question)

My question is that why don't we just make the "serviceConsumer" method to be like

```
public static void serviceConsumer(Service s) { 
    s.method1(); 
    s.method2(); 
}
```

In this case, the code depends on the interface "Service" but not the implementation. (It can also "swap" transparently, isn't it?). So, I don't really get to the point of using "factory" here and what it states at start.

-----------------------------below quoted from "Thinking in Java"------------------------------

```
//: interfaces/Factories.java 
import static net.mindview.util.Print.*;
interface Service {
    void method1();
    void method2();
}
interface ServiceFactory {
    Service getService();
}
class Implementation1 implements Service {
    Implementation1() {} // Package access 
    public void method1() {
        print("Implementation1 method1");
    }
    public void method2() {
        print("Implementation1 method2");
    }
}
class Implementation1Factory implements ServiceFactory {
    public Service getService() {
        return new Implementation1();
    }
}
class Implementation2 implements Service {
    Implementation2() {} // Package access 
    public void method1() {
        print("Implementation2 method1");
    }
    public void method2() {
        print("Implementation2 method2");
    }
}
class Implementation2Factory implements ServiceFactory {
    public Service getService() {
        return new Implementation2();
    }
}
public class Factories {
    public static void serviceConsumer(ServiceFactory fact) {
        Service s = fact.getService();
        s.method1();
        s.method2();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        serviceConsumer(new Implementation1Factory());
        // Implementations are completely interchangeable: 
        serviceConsumer(new Implementation2Factory());
    }
}
/* Output: 
Implementation1 method1 
Implementation1 method2 
Implementation2 method1 
Implementation2 method2 
*/ //:~
```

Answer (score 2):

Well nothing prevents you from writing such method, the quoted statement is about creation of the object itself.

> In this case, the code depends on the interface "Service" but not the implementation

In both cases the code depends on the interface, the difference is, that in your implementation the `Service` is created outside the method `serviceConsumer`

Comment: Oh, ic. However, if it is ok to skip the "factory", then why it adds more layer to complicate things? Is that we need to go a step further, to assume the creation of "Service" object could be very complicated and it worth a factory to do so?

Comment: The factory is essential here. The thing is that you're looking at the effect of the factory (which is dropping dependency on the implementation) without taking into account existence of this factory.
Take a broader look at it. If you weren't using factory for creating Service and instead created object by yourself in many places (which in fact is introducing the dependency on implementation), then after the change of implementation of Service interface, you would have to change many object creations instead of changing one piece of code in factory.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be clearer if you see a real use of Factory Method. The TIJ example is without any context.

My favorite example is `Collection.iterator()`, where `Collection` is the `ServiceFactory` and `Iterator` is the `Service`. You can see the calls in the `serviceConsumer()` but think of the following:

```
Collection c = new ArrayList();  // ArrayList is a Factory for its iterator
Iterator i = c.iterator();  // getService()
if (i.hasNext()) { ...}
```

If `serviceConsumer` were a method to print the collection (instead of something without context), you could see how passing an `ServiceFactory` (`ArrayList`) is better than passing the `Service` (`Iterator`). There is more encapsulation using that (the details of the Service are hidden in the method).

Here are some UML diagrams to help understand the similarities:

#### Factory method pattern

[image: UML for factory method similar to GoF]

#### TIJ Example

[image: UML for the TIJ example]

#### Collection.iterator()

[image: UML for the factory method pattern used in Collection.iterator()]

Note: The pink classes are actually anonymous classes that implement the Iterator interface type that corresponds to the Collection. They're not normally classes a client will instantiate any other way (hidden).